# I am trying to run this demo script for my automation practice. But the chrome isn't running

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to execute the script but it is not executing and keep giving this error, which i tried to resolve but it is not. Please advice what actions to be taken from my end.

### CODE BELOW

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

import time

class demofindelementbyID():
    def locate_find_id(self):
        driver = webdriver.Chrome()
        driver.get("https://secure.yatra.com/social/common/yatra/signin.htm")
        driver.maximize_window()
        driver.find_element(By.ID, 'login-input').send_keys('test@test.com')
        time.sleep(4)

findbyid = demofindelementbyID()
findbyid.locate_find_id()
```

### ERROR:

```
C:\Users\CN323\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\python.exe D:\PycharmProjects\python-selenium-MV\LearningSelenium\FirstAutomationTest.py 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\CN323\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 38, in get_path
    path = SeleniumManager().driver_location(options) if path is None else path
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\CN323\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\selenium_manager.py", line 90, in driver_location
    output = self.run(args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\CN323\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\selenium_manager.py", line 138, in run
    raise WebDriverException(f"Unsuccessful command executed: {command}.\n{result}{stderr}")
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: Unsuccessful command executed: C:\Users\CN323\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\windows\selenium-manager.exe --browser chrome --output json.
{'code': 65, 'message': 'error sending request for url (https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/known-good-versions-with-downloads.json): error trying to connect: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. (os error 10054)', 'driver_path': '', 'browser_path': ''}


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:\PycharmProjects\python-selenium-MV\LearningSelenium\FirstAutomationTest.py", line 5, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome()
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\CN323\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 45, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\CN323\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 51, in __init__
    self.service.path = DriverFinder.get_path(self.service, options)
                        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\CN323\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\driver_finder.py", line 41, in get_path
    raise NoSuchDriverException(msg) from err
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchDriverException: Message: Unable to obtain driver for chrome using Selenium Manager.; For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors/driver_location


Process finished with exit code 1
```

I just need want to get this script run successfully. Thats it. Any help will be greatly appreciated

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than on other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it is for others to read and understand it.

Comment: Just upgrade your selenium to latest one which is `v4.12.0`

Comment: @Shawn Oh dear....how silly of me!  It solved the problem.  It was 4.11. 
 I upgraded to 4.12. It is working now. Thanks a lot.